# In Python, find out number of differences between two ordered lists

Tags: python, list

I want to compare two lists of same length

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [1, 2, 5, 7, 3]
```

and find out the number of differences `n`, in this case it'll be `n = 2`, and also return an error if the length are not equal. What's the pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use [the `sum()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
def differences(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        raise ValueError("Lists of different length.")
    return sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

We loop over the lists together using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and then compare them. As `True == 1` and `False == 0`, we just sum this to get the number of differences. Another option would be to use the conditional part of the generator expression:

```
sum(1 for i, j in zip(a, b) if i != j)
```

I can't really say I feel one is more readable than the other, and doubt there will be a performance difference.

Comment: I prefer the explicit `1 for i`, instead of the implicit boolean (relying on it being an `int`), but anyway +1 ( as long it's explicit the length check)

Comment: @JonClements I agree, and yet then the important part (the comparison) is pushed to the end of the expression, which feels awkward. I keep on changing my mind as to which I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution that also produces an error if the length is not equal:

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x,y: bool(x-y),a,b))
2
```

Now try the input of different length:

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x,y: bool(x-y),[1,2],[1]))
TypeError
```

How it works: bool(x,y) returns True if elements are different. Then we map this function on 2 lists and get the list [False, True, False, True, False].
If we put into the function map() the lists of different length, we get the TypeError

Finally, the function sum() of this boolean list gives 2.

Comment: Note that `map()` and `lambda` are generally slower and less readable than a list comp/generator expression, and this will only work for numbers.

Comment: yes, they are slower, but the code is much shorter, it depends on what is needed (exaggerating, in need for speed, don't use python :)). What is more readable is a very subjective matter. You're right that this doesn't work on types where the "-" operation isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks for another solution. I prefer @Lattyware's solution because personally I feel that's more readable. I'm not familiar with `lambda` function. Also with his solution I can define the error message so I know what error I got.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Cast both to a set, then find difference between the two. For example:

```
>>> a = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> b = [1,2,5,7,2]
>>> len(set(a) -  set(b))
2
```

This could be wrapped up in a function to check for length differences first.

Comment: This won't work if there are repeated elements, and doesn't take order into account. `difference([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [9, 7, 5, 3, 1])` would be `0` as opposed to `4`. The OP's example counts `3` as being different, despite it existing in both lists (that is, position matters). This also ignores the possibility of lists being different lengths, as was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that last 3, and had used 2 in my example. My bad! I mentioned that a function could be used to check differences, as per your example code.